# How to make a window normal size with the keyboard in Unity?

Tags: 10.10, unity

I have 10.10 Netbook Edition (with Unity).  If I hold down the Super key, I see numbers on the the app icons (including apps that are already open).  If I hit the number for an app that is already open (say Firefox), it opens all my Firefox windows in a small version.

At this point I can actually interact with the small versions of the Firefox windows and use Alt-Tab to switch between them. But what if I want to select one of the Firefox windows to be normal size?  I know I can click on it to do that, but how do I do it with the keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know that isn't possible in 10.10's Unity. In 11.04, you can switch between those windows using the arrow keys and hitting enter.